# Does JUser/save method triggers onUserAfterSave event?

Tags: joomla-3.4

Does the method to save the JUser object to the database, JUser/save, triggers the onUserAfterSave event?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Thanks,
Omri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does, if `onUserBeforeSave` event dosen't result in any errors. See [source code](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/joomla/user/user.php#L807).